# Function describing an adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

I understand that an isothermic process, plotted on a PV diagram, can be described by a rectangular hyperbola.

However, now I am wondering, what about an adiabatic process, what function best describes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isothermal process is a rectangular hyperbola on a PV diagram only for an ideal gas. It follows from the equation of state $pV = N k T$ which shows that at fixed $N$ and $T$ we have $p \propto 1/V$. Assuming you are asking about the shape of an adiabatic process also for an ideal gas, this is given by the equation
$$
p \propto V^{-\gamma}
$$
where $\gamma = c_p / c_v = (c_v + R)/c_v$  (here $c_v$ and $c_p$ are the molar heat capacities and $R$ is the molar gas constant). This can be proved using the equations of state for the ideal gas and the fact that the change in internal energy is equal to the work done for an adiabatic process.